# find lists of intersecting arrays

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm

Here is my data set:

```
isects = [[3],[2,3],[1,3],[0,1,2],[]]
```

Here are some visualizations of the patterns in my data set:

[image: polygons intersecting]

[image: clique graph]

Each element is a list of the indexes that element intersects.  So, the element @0 only intersects element 3.  While the element @3 intersects element 0, 1, and 2.

I want to create a list of the intersections between these elements.  I want greater numbers of intersections at the end of the list.  For my sample set, the solution would look like this:

```
[[0,3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2,3]]
```

*That is, 0 & 3 intersect, as do 1 & 2, 1 & 3, and 2 & 3.  Finally, 1 & 2 & 3 all intersect each other.*

***As pointed out in the comments below, it is possible that 1 & 2 & 3 do not all intersect if they were actually polygons, but for my purposes I am assuming all listed elements can and will intersect each other.***

What is the fastest way to get this data only using the `isects` list?

Comment: Do you already have an algorithm in mind?  If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure you have enough data in `isects` to determine if 1, 2, and 3 intersect

Comment: Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with ```isects``` and add the indices to the sub-lists.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh you are right -- in my diagram poly2 could be shifted to the right and prevent the intersection of all 3 polygons.  However, I am assuming they do intersect for my purposes.

Comment: first: calculate bounding Boxes, check overlapping of BBs, than:  0.BB.MIN_X<1.vertex[N]<0.BB.MAX_X and 0.BB.MIN_Y<1.vertex[N]<0.BB.MAX_Y........so you are checking, "is vertex 1 of polygone 1 in the BB of polygone 3"...... you can do that with isects, but you need more data

Comment: Have you taken a look at `shapely`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I understand, isects list does not provide full information about intersection cases - it is not possible to know about triple intersection from it. So geometric approach is needed to get what intersections do occur.

**Edit** If you are not interested in real geometric intersections, then you have to solve graph problem: you have adjacency list, and want to get... what? It seems that all possible [K-size cliques with K=2 and more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).

Wiki example:

[image]

> The graph shown has one maximum clique, the triangle {1,2,5}, and four
>   more maximal cliques, the pairs {2,3}, {3,4}, {4,5}, and {4,6}.

[Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) is relatively effective for searching for all cliques (while complexity is O(3^(n/3)). It is usually used to find maximal clique but can find all size ones.

Comment: thank you, but i am trying to solve the problem only using the data in the `isects` array

Comment: I've updated the post.  You are right, and I am sorry, the polygons were included to help visualize the dataset and ended up causing confusion.  I want to find all combinations of intersections in my dataset.  Unfamiliar with the 'clique problem` as formally presented there, but yes, that does seem correct.

Comment: Bron-Kerbosch algorithm (not fast, but better than exhaustive brute-force)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a table intersections with the isect data.

```
  0 1 2 3 4
0 -     x
1   - x x
2   x - x
3 x x x -
4         -
```

Each 'x' represents an intersection.  Intersections are sets, so [0,1] and [1,0] are the same.  Thus we get the unique list of intersections: [0,3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3].

And if you want to consider when other polygons overlap the same one a common intersection, then look at '-'s which are surrounded by 'x's.  In this case, you'd have just one (at 2x2), thus you'd have [1,2,3] as an overlapping intersection.  *However, I agree with everyone else here, the data in isect does not guarantee there is an overlap.*